# Como retornar valores de colunas diferentes sem repetir?

Tags: php, sql

Estou tentando capturar e printar na tela todas as categorias de uma tabela, porém não gostaria que elas se repetissem.
Repare que há 4 colunas de categorias diferentes abaixo:

```
NUMEROID-----NOME-----CATEGORIA1-----CATEGORIA2-----CATEGORIA3-----CATEGORIA4
00001      wordart      Jogos         Saude          Saude         Culinaria
00002      wonderl      Noticias      Noticias       Jogos         Arte
00003      heaveng      Arte          Jogos          Jogos         Jogos
00004      flowwav      Arte          Saude          Jogos         Saude
```

Gostaria printar(em php) na tela uma lista como no exemplo abaixo:
(Se possível em ordem alfabética)

- Arte
- Culinaria
- Jogos
- Noticias
- Saude

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de resolver só na query:

```
     SELECT CATEGORIA1 AS CATEGORIA FROM NOME_DA_TABLE
     UNION
     SELECT CATEGORIA2 AS CATEGORIA FROM NOME_DA_TABLE
     UNION
     SELECT CATEGORIA3 AS CATEGORIA FROM NOME_DA_TABLE
     UNION
     SELECT CATEGORIA4 AS CATEGORIA FROM NOME_DA_TABLE

O Union irá fazer o trabalho!
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asphttp://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp